# Adding Google Tag Manager to a Flutter Project duplicates Firebase events and spams a lot of screen_view events (8k) at startup

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, events, google-tag-manager

I am having a problem with firebase analytics, after adding Google tag manager to the project, Firebase starts sending duplicate events (for each event) and at app startup the "screen_view" event is spamed multiple times (5k-10k events).
Details:

- the problem is on Android, the app is written using Flutter.
- I have the latest version for the Firebase Analytics plugin (9.1.7)
- I have double checked the implementations
- if I remove the GTM line from gradle the problem goes away. (implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:18.0.1')
- the flutter version is also kept up to date

I've tried contacting firebase support but all they did was to redirect me from department to department with no insight or help whatsoever.

Has anybody encountered this and if yes, did you manage to fix this?

Comment: have you got any solution to stop triggering screen_view event from GTM ?